# Where is the 'value' variable set in properties?

Tags: c#

In C# properties, where is the 'value' variable defined? I can see it used in the bodies of setters before it is defined anywhere.

```
namespace TestBindings
{
    public class Dog
    {
        private decimal age;
        private string name;
        private const int AgeFactor = 7;

        public Dog(decimal age, string name)
        {
            this.age = age;
            this.name = name;
        }

        public decimal AgeDogYears
        {
            get { return age / AgeFactor; }
            set { age = value * AgeFactor; }
        }

        public decimal AgeHumanYears
        {
            get { return age; }
            set { age = value; } //here
        }

        public string Name
        {
            get { return name; }
            set { name = value; } // and here
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: FYI, you should not store `Age` as a property. It should be calculated from `DateTime Birthdate { get; set; }`

Comment: It's an example

Comment: [value (C# Reference)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/value)

Comment: It's a wiki answer. If you feel you can improve it, edit an answer or post it. I originally was using it because a newbie on Reddit I was helping used this exact language looking for an answer, and figured I could make the question and answer once. I don't understand why you are commenting on the question and giving me a hard time?

Comment: Sorry you're having a hard time. I don't understand why, though? You asked a fairly easy, straight-forward question and I was trying to help with both your example and the answer. How was my comment hard for you, so I can improve? I was also going to tell you that you don't see `value` in getters (as the question states). Hope that is not also giving you a hard time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 'value' variable is automatically passed in from the use-site and is a pre-defined variable name for the value passed in the set expression.

e.g.

```
var jack = new Dog(13, "jack");
jack.Name = "Jackson";
```

Here the value after the = sign is being passed into the setter defined in the class as 'value'.

```
        public string Name
        {
            get { return name; }
            set { name = value; } //here
        }
```

It's roughly equivalent to the Java expression it replaces of having an explicit getter and setter method, just using different syntax in order to unify settings fields and properties.

e.g.

```
public class Dog {
    private double age;
    private String name;
    private final int AgeFactor = 7;

    public Dog(double age, String name) {
        this.age = age;
        this.name = name;
    }

    public double getAgeHumanYears() {
        return age;
    }

    public void setAgeHumanYears(double value) {
        this.age = value;
    }

    public double getAgeDogYears() {
        return age / AgeFactor;
    }

    public void setAgeDogYears(double value) {
        age = value * AgeFactor;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

}
```

With our test changing to.

```
private Dog jack = new Dog(13, "jack");
jack.setName("Jackson");
```